# Bad performance IE using documentFragment

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-manipulation

To test DOM manipulation versus innerHTML I deviced this little test method using a `documentFragment` ([web page](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/)) to append 10000 `href` elements to a `div` element. The performance is ok for Chrome or Firefox, but in IE (10, 9, 8) it's dramatically bad, it takes around ***10-12 seconds***. Can anyone explain this difference and/or elaborate on a solution to enhance performance for IE?

Here's a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/kW5dd/) demonstrating it.

The method:

```
function useFragment(){
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        i = 10000,
        rval = document.createElement('span');
    frag.appendChild(rval);
    do {
     var optText = 'option '+i
        ,ref = document.createElement('a') 
        ,zebra = i%2 ? 'zebra' : ''
        ,islist = true
        ,isSel = i === 5
     ;
     rval.insertBefore(ref,rval.firstChild);
     ref.appendChild(document.createTextNode(optText));
     ref.id = 'opt' + i;
     ref.className = zebra + (islist && isSel ? ' scrollSelect' : '');
     ref.href = '#' + i;
     ref.title = optText;
   } while (i-->0);
   return rval;
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of document fragments before...

Comment: Hi Jan, added link to a Resig article on the subject.

Comment: I think the way you measure the time is flawed. For example, you define the `useInnerHtmlBttn.onclick` handler inside the timed region for the fragment timing.

Comment: That may be the case (jsfiddle is adjusted now), but the basic point is that IE is very, very slow using this method. Apart from the fact that the IE monstrum is always slower and always needs tweeking to make things work, I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Your measurements disagree with the observation made in the article you linked.

Comment: I still see the original fiddle, r1 looks like an old version and r2 doesn't exist.

Comment: '*Your measurements disagree ...*' => that's the point of this question ;)
It's the fiddles base version that is updated.

Comment: You still include the `useInnerHtmlBttn.onclick` definition (and many other things that could happen asynchronously on the page load) into the timed section.

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/kW5dd/show/light/, and see what IE's profiler has to say.

Comment: My measurements say 4 seconds and 2 seconds, but the observed time is much longer than two seconds. No idea why

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think I've found it: it looks like, although a `documentFragment` should be an 'off line' element (an element that is not part of the live DOM) *IE doesn't treat it as such*. The way to force the fragment to *really* be off line is to append some element to it, set its `display` property to `none` and append the rest of elements to that element. After you are done, remove the `display:none` property and the `documentFragment` can be appended to the DOM.

It is still three times slower (on my PC it still takes around 1-1.5 seconds, versus around 2-300 ms in Chrome/Firefox for 10000 elements). So, for IE (even version 10), using `innerHTML` to add a bunch of elements to the DOM is the faster way. IE remains a developers nightmare, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience goes the best benefits are to append a lot isolated elements to the fragment and to append that element not before all children and attributes are fixed (post append).
If I understand your code (I'm to lazy to decode it really) there is one span you append to the fragment. This is not the sense of documentFragment. By the way: You shouldn't declare your vars in a loop.

```
var node=document.getElementById("whatever")
   ,frag=document.createDocumentFragment()
   ,i=0,len=50,a={},img={};
for(i;i<len;i++){
   a=document.createElement("a");
   img=document.createElement("img");
   a.href="image"+i;
   img.className=J[i][1];
   img.src="image/img"+i+".png";
   img.alt="image:"+i;
   a.appendChild(img);
   frag.appendChild(a);
   }                     
node.appendChild(frag);
```

This way IE8 Opera12 takes quite the same time than innerHTML. The real benefit has chrome. FF is unbelievable fast with innerHTML. Tested on an old XP machine.

Another thing to think of is to create a node not connected to the DOM with all children and attributes, to clone it several times, to manipulate it and to append it to a documentFragment.

```
var frag=document.createDocumentFragment()
   ,toFill=document.getElementById("imageCollection")
   ,i=0,a={},img={}
   ,dummy=document.createElement("a")
   ;
dummy.innerHTML="<img src='img/image_' />";   
for(i;i<50;i++){
   a=dummy.cloneNode(true);
   img=a.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
   a.href="description_"+i+".html";
   img.src+=i+".png";
   frag.appendChild(a);
   }            
toFill.appendChild(frag);
```

This is useful if you don't need to make a lot of manipulations on the cloned node.