# Why IE8 is faster than IE9 on this javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Like in the title I have quite unusual problem. I'm working on web app which has a view which is rendered quite fast in IE8 and much slower in IE9.

Profiler says that the most time consuming function is this:

```
function handleTree(request, rootTagName) {
  var text = request.responseText;
  var startIndex = text.indexOf("<" + rootTagName + ">");
  var endIndex = text.indexOf("</" + rootTagName + ">");
  var newHtml = text.substring(startIndex + rootTagName.length + 2, endIndex);
  var treeContainer = getCachedElement("tree");
  treeContainer.innerHTML = newHtml;
  AjaxRequestEnd();

}
```

I checked in debugger and only in the line

```
treeContainer.innerHTML = newHtml;
```

execution stops for a while. The *treeContainer* is an empty *div* element. The inserted html is pretty big so I suppose it's because of constructing the dom tree.

But still, before IE even calls this function, it's hanging for a few seconds. As I mentioned, on IE8 everything works faster. Any ideas?

Edit: I know I didn't provide too detailed description but I don't have any ideas what else can be important in this context.

Comment: Is the HTML valid you are shoving into the element?

Comment: Yes, no errors logged.

Comment: Please do not use string manipulation to parse HTML, consider using the DOM API instead.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the string manipulation you are doing before assigning the `innerHTML` property. A regular expression might speeds things up:

```
function handleTree(request, rootTagName) {
  var treeContainer = getCachedElement("tree");

  treeContainer.style.display = "none";
  treeContainer.innerHTML = request.responseText
    .replace(new RegExp("<" + rootTagName + ">(.+?)</" + rootTagName + ">"), "$1");
  treeContainer.style.display = "";

  AjaxRequestEnd();
}
```

If that doesn't help, you are probably running into a performance issue in IE9 when it parses the HTML.

This other Stack Overflow question might be worth a read too:

[Bad performance IE using documentFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080365/bad-performance-ie-using-documentfragment)

The `treeContainer`, if visible and attached to the document, might be treated differently. Try setting its display style to "none", then set the innerHTML, then set the display back to an empty string to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestions, I'll test those when I get the access to the right machine (it may take a 'while').

Comment: There should be new RegExp() I guess... Anyway, I tested it and no success. Still slow.

Comment: It's likely a performance issue with parsing HTML in those versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's possible but I'm not sure and I can't see any way to test it. I'll fix this with avoiding ajax in here.