# IE DOM manipulation performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance, internet-explorer, dom

I encountered severe performance issue when my JS code runs under IE (10, 11). It is 10 times slower when compared to another browsers.

I did some profiling and it seems that `innerHTML` and `createElement` is super slow.

I tried to optimize using `createDocumentFragment`, which even speed up my code in other browsers, but performance under IE remains intact.

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
        function a() { 
            var CNT = 100000;
            var start, end, time;
            start = window.performance.now();
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            for (var i = 0, l = CNT; i < l; ++i) {
                var el = document.createElement('div');
                el.innerHTML = i;
                frag.appendChild(el);
            }
            document.body.appendChild(frag);
            end = window.performance.now();
            time = end - start;
            console.log('time', time);
        }
        a();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to optimize using string concatenation to avoid costly DOM operations, which made it much more faster, but still very slow when comparing to other browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
        function a() {
            var CNT = 100000;
            var start, end, time;
            start = window.performance.now();
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            var content = '';
            for (var i = 0, l = CNT; i < l; ++i) {
                content += '<div>' + i + '</div>';
            }
            var holder = document.createElement('div');
            holder.innerHTML = content;
            frag.appendChild(holder);
            document.body.appendChild(frag);
            end = window.performance.now();
            time = end - start;
            console.log('time', time);
        } 
        a();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to make dynamic DOM fast in IE? I need to generate quite large DOM trees using Javascript with some templating and IE performance is just a killer in this case.

Any help?

Comment: I found something related though at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080365/bad-performance-ie-using-documentfragment

Comment: It may be the screen refresh which is slow, you might try doing the insert during the animationFrame using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft themselves advise against using `innerHtml`, and use `createTextNode` + `appendChild` instead - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If I were you I'd refactor the code first.